# Hadoop learning development workflow with Eclipse and AWS

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, hadoop

I have Installed a single node hadoop 2.8 on AWS free tier nano instance. I have a local windows machine with eclipse on it. What is a good learning workflow. I am not sure of capabilities of AWS orhadoop. Should I write code in local eclipse build a jar, transfer it AWS machine and run it?

If I have to write and create a jar from local machine should I have hadoop installed? how should I do? and What is good learning path from installation to being comfortable with working on hadoop?

Comment: A lot of cloud vendors offer virtual machine images that come preloaded with cloud software (hadoop +  spark + etc). The one I have used is Cloudera Live VM (https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-8.html). Another popular cloud vendor is Hortonworks. I find this desirable to a nano instance as your home computer likely has way more resources than a nano VM.

Comment: @jeff thank you for your reply, I have a 4gb machine at home. So i wont be able to run VM. For now I am trying simple MR programs using a script to build a jar locally and running it in nano vm.